# JQuery - slowly bg-image changing

Tags: jquery, effects

I'm trying to make my hover-action with slowly bg-image changing.

```
.menu_part
{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    background-image: url(../images/bg_menu.png);
    float:left;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}

.menu_part:hover
{
    background-image: url(../images/bg_menu_hove.png);                            
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Menu:

```
<div id="head_menu">
    <a href="#order"><div>make order</div></a>
    <a href="#portfolio"><div>portfolie</div></a>
    <a href="#contacts"><div>contacts</div></a>
    <a href="#vacancies"><div>vacancies</div></a>
    <a href="#about"><div>about company</div></a>
</div>
```

Some JQuery:

```
$('#head_menu a').addClass('menu_part');
```

Now I'm trying to write hover-action for selector $('#head_menu a'). Could i change bg-image to need, when hover, slowly?

---

Here is my trying-code:

```
    $("#head_menu a").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).animate({backgroundImage: 'url(images/bg_menu_hove.png)', color: '#fff'}, 1000);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).animate({backgroundImage: 'url(images/bg_menu.png)', color: '#000'}, 1000);                
        }
    );
```

But it even doesn't show menu now. What i did wrong? And I'll also try to use bg-position.

---

Here is code with bg-position, I can't understand. I merged **bg_menu.png** and **bg_menu_hove.png** into 1 image 200px+200px.
Style above doesn't work even without JQuery.

```
.menu_part:hover
{
    background-image: url(../images/new_menu.png);
    background-position: 0 -200px;
}
```

Comment: When you say "change slowly", d'you mean that you want one image to fade in to the next, or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, standard technics for hover effects with changing background is merge both of pictures. So, stick `bg_menu_hove.png` to `bg_menu.png` after that, just play with position of background.

Remove `div` from `a` tag (div is block element and a is inline... it could be vice versa).

Now if we have only one image, use for example `animate` function from `jQuery` of course (`backgroundPosition`).
Take a look on nice example, and really useful site for begginer: http://visualjquery.com/
(click: `Effects -> Custom -> Animate`)

Comment: Actually yes, this is a better idea than mine - just combine the images into one (sprite) image, then use animate() to move the backgroundPosition.

Comment: I'll try to use bgPos, but look, please, at my update in post. It doesn't work with animate.

Comment: My fault - I didn't realise that animate didn't work with backgroundPosition. Try this: http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able do this with the jquery [animate](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) function, and some slight changes to the CSS - something like:

```
.menu_part
{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    background-image: url(../images/bg_menu_hove.png);
    float:left;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}

.menu_part div
{
    background-image: url(../images/bg_menu.png);                            
    color: #FFF;
}
```

And then:

```
$('#head_menu a').addClass('menu_part');

$('.menu_part').bind('mouseover', function() {

    $(this).find('div').animate({ 
        opacity: 0
      }, 1500 );

});

$('.menu_part').bind('mouseout', function() {

    $(this).find('div').animate({ 
        opacity: 1
      }, 1500 );

});
```

Couldn't test it at the moment, sorry - but you get the basic idea.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the built in animate won't work for this, as it doesn't even handle color transitions.   The more powerful animate in jQuery UI may be able to handle it though.

Comment: But it does handle opacity, which is all we're doing here.

Comment: Yeah I'd concentrate on Rinz's answer below, it's a better solution.